# AngularJS - ng-include doesn't work on ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-ng-include, ng-view

I have a function to include html files on click. The problem is that it doesn't work when under ng-view (using $routeProvider), while it works fine outside of ng-view. I suspect that moving the include function from controller to service might help, but I am unsure how to do that as I'm new to Angular.

HTML when it works:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <ng-include src="'views/main.html'" ng-controller="mainCtrl"></ng-include>
</body>
```

HTML when it doesn't work:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

main.html:

```
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="include('temp1.html')">Block 1</button><i ng-click="delete('temp1.html')">DEL 1</i>

    <button ng-click="include('temp2.html')">Block 2</button><i ng-click="delete('temp2.html')">DEL 2</i>

    <button ng-click="include('temp3.html')">Block 3</button><i ng-click="delete('temp3.html')">DEL 3</i>

    <div ng-repeat="template in templates">
      <div ng-include="template.url">Content from blocks goes here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

APP.js:

```
   angular
  .module('MyApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

mainCtrl:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.templates=[];

$scope.include = function(templateURI) {
   var template={url:templateURI};
   $scope.templates.push(template);
   console.log($scope.templates);
}

$scope.delete= function(url){
  removeEntity($scope.templates,url);
}

var removeEntity = function(elements,url){
  elements.forEach(function(element,index){
    if(element.url===url){
      elements.splice(index,1);  
    }
  })
}
```

The above "include" function does not work with $routeProvider. It works fine when used outside the ng-view, without $routeProvider. Would moving the 'include' function from mainCtrl to the serrvice would do the trick?
Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `<ng-include src="'view/main.html'" >` view/main.html...

and in ur route there is `templateUrl: 'views/main.html'`..
you should correct ur template url to view/main.html..

Comment: thanks but that was just a typo and my URLs are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In main.html

```
 <div ng-controller="MyController">
```

and in app.js

```
$routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      })
```

different controllers....

Comment: Sorry but that was yet another typo, I changed some ctrls intentionally. The naming here is not a problem.